# Critical discharge UPower level of Aspire Acer One AOA150

Tags: power-supply, gnome, acer-aspire, debian-stretch

Trying to get a reliable estimation when it is time to switch from
battery to power supply (or shut down the netbook).

Using GNOME battery status applet and upower tool (they are coherent). At present when
the percentage is about 50% the netbook abruptly turns off with no warning
or a chance to shutdown proper.

Possible explanations:

- 50% is the critical discharge level
- UPower's algorithm of calculating the discharge level doesn't fit the hardware I have.

In the latter case I'd appreciate any hint how to fix it.

Experimentally I found that it takes five hours for the netbook to turn off.

```
Netbook: Aspire Acer One AOA-150 
Battery model: UM08A71
System: Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
UPower client version 0.99.4
GNOME Shell 3.22.3
```

Additionally

```
$ upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT)
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               SIMPLO
  model:                UM08A71
  serial:               1000
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 08 Mar 2019 04:20:30 PM EET (65 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              144.023 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         144.023 Wh
    energy-full-design:  96.1038 Wh
    energy-rate:         3.7407 W
    voltage:             12.523 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1552054830  3.741   fully-charged
```

where

```
$ upower -e | grep BAT
```

returns /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1. I found no clue what is this.

Update I:

Experimented with

```
# powerstat
```

and

```
# powertop -c
```

They both overestimated battery time by far (by three hours or more).

Update II:

After running powerstat, "powertop -c" the situation became worse: now upower promises that more than 9 hours of battery time remains, while from the experience I know that in less than 2 hours the netbook turns off.

Update III:
Does UPower takes into account the battery full capacity? Is it configurable? I have failed to find it.

Comment: Have you calibrated the battery recently?  See https://www.howtogeek.com/172271/how-to-calibrate-your-laptops-battery-for-accurate-battery-life-estimates/

Comment: The behavior was there from the very date of purchasing the new
battery. At about 50% discharge the netbook just turns off. No
Hibernate, no HybridSleep, no nothing. Since the remaining battery
life is estimated wrong, it is understandable why none of these
actions take place.

GNOME I'm using has no similarity with what is shown in the article
you referenced. What GNOME has doesn't work because of the above
reasons.

Comment: Tried to 'apt-get install hibernate'.

apt-get complained of some missing firmware during installation. The
battery percentage is now always 100%.  'sudo hibernate' doesn't
hibernate , just shuts down the netbook. I removed hibernate and the
realistic figures of battery percentages have been restored.

Comment: When netbook turns off upower and GNOME battery applet both show the
discharge percentage of about 47%. When I turn the netbook on again
the percentage is less than 4%.

Comment: Now upower shows 100% battery percentage during two hours. This
coincidented with my several repeated attempts to 'calibrate' the
battery (fully charge the battery and wait when netbook turns off)

Comment: Something went totally wrong with upower. The netbook is on battery
for four hours and a half and upower still tells me the battery is 100%
full.